# Python Bitwise Operation function

Tags: python

Can someone please explain what does this code do? I understand mostly what each bitwise operation does but I fail to see the full purpose of this code.

```
def get_bit(byte, bit_num):
    '''
    @param int byte: a given byte
    @param int bit_num: a specific bit number within the 
    @rtype: int
    >>> get_bit(0b00000101, 2)
    1
    '''
    return (byte & (1 << bit_num)) >> bit_num
```

Comment: It's exactly what it says. Given a byte and a bit position it returns the value of that bit

Comment: Why don't you try using it.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Thanks, makes sense now.